# socket programming for bad network

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

client:

```
socket(), connect() and then 
for (1 to 1024) { 
   write(1024 bytes)
}
exit(0);
```

server:

```
socket(), bind(), listen()
while (1) {
  accept()
  while((n = read()) {
     if (n == -1) abort(); /* never happended */
     total_read += n
  }
  close()
}
```

now, client runs on Mac under NAT and server runs on my VPS (abroad)

generally, it works fine (client send all data and exit & server recv all data)

however, when client is running but suddenly the network is broken for couple minutes(and regain), the client won't exit after a long long time... I kill it with control + C and run it again, the server seems not read the data any more (client is still running)

here is what netstat shows:

client:

```
tcp4       0 130312  192.168.1.254.58573    A.B.C.D.8888    ESTABLISHED
```

server:

```
tcp        0      0 A.B.C.D:8888     a.b.c.d:54566      ESTABLISHED 10970/a.out     
tcp   102136      0 A.B.C.D:8888     a.b.c.d:60916      ESTABLISHED -
```

A.B.C.D is my VPS address
a.b.c.d is my public client address

my quesiton is:

1, why ?

2, server will works fine after restarting, how to write code to get rid of it without restarting ?

Answer (score 4):

In TCP, there's no way to tell that a connection has failed unless you try to send something on the connection.  TCP doesn't perform active monitoring of the connection (actually, there are optional "keepalive" packets, but these are not normally sent until the connection has been idle for a couple of hours). When you send something, you'll eventually get an error if there's a timeout waiting for the other machine to return an acknowledgement. But if you're just reading data without sending, you can't tell that the connection has failed -- it just looks like the sender doesn't have anything to send.

You can resolve this by designing your application so that the client is required to send something every N seconds. Then set a timer in the server that detects that you haven't received anything for more than N seconds (you should add a little extra time to allow for transient delays).

Comment: thx
just like NOOP in FTP
I wanna know something about RecvQ & SendQ from netstat. There are two item in the server's netstat, the 1st one seems to be the newer connection, but the 2nd is the old. May be the newer connection's data is send to the old one, I guess...

Comment: Good answer. Here's what I don't get. Shouldn't the client socket get implicitly closed as a result of the process exiting? Therefore closing the connection and the server read() call returning 0 ?  It actually doesn't matter, robust server socket code should be written for all kinds of possibilities and have a reasonable timeout value to handle a dead connection.

Comment: When the client exits, it will send a FIN to the server. If the network is up, the server will receive this, read EOF and exit the loop. But if the network is down, the server will never receive this.

Answer (score -1):

When the network is broken what happens is that you clients keep sending data and at some point the socket send buffer gets full (I understand from what you show that you are sending 1024 Bytes, 1024 times, 1MB in total). The default for send buffer could be 16KB (surely less than 1MB). Then when the client tries to write, it gets blocked forever.

BTW, now I'm answering your question I don't know whether eventually after a number of TCP timeouts, TCP gives up and closes the socket making the socket interface return with error. I think that's not happening ... :) - So, connect fails if there is a problem in the network but write and read do not fail.

In the server side, the server gets blocked in read because it never receives the EOF.

Solution:

In the client side use non-blocking sockets, if the network is broken, at some point write will return with error EWOULDBLOCK. Then you will realize the send buffer is full for some reason. At that point, you could clouse the connection and try to connect again. If the network is broken, you will receive an error.

In the server side also use non-blocking sockets and select() function with a timeout. After a few timeouts you may decide there is a problem with the new connection and close it.

Comment: write() does fail if there is a network problem. The sender does not get blocked forever. TCP times out the retries and resets the connection, delivering an ECONNRESET to the sender. The default send buffer size is platform dependent. A read timeout would solve the read() problem. Non-blocking I/O is neither necessary nor a solution here. Too much misinformation and guesswork. -1

Comment: @EJP, you're correct the client does not get blocked forever, just for a very long time. Then a write fails with a host unreachable error EHOSTUNREACH, if you try to write again it will return with EPIPE. I'm not aware that write could receive ECONNRESET, read can receive it for a reset connection. Of course the default send buffer size is platform dependent but it is usually some Kilobytes and not 1MB. You're right a read timeout will solve the problem. Non-blocking I/O could not be necessary for you but it could certainly be a way to solve it.

Comment: EHOSTUNREACH only happens during connect(). read() can receive ECONNRESET, and so can write(). Non-blocking I/O doesn't solve this problem. It just prevents you from blocking while TCP is detecting the problem. That still takes the same amount of time. Closing a connection just because the send buffer is full is a poor recommendation.

Comment: @EJP, that's wrong. EHOSTUNREACH is set as a pending error for a socket when there is a segment sent that cannot reach the destination node. It can happen on connect or write. You won’t see the error ECONNRESET unless a segment with RST set is received. You can see how it works in the Linux Kernel, for example in function ip_queue_xmit used by TCP to send a segment to the IP layer. I can also provide you a client-server example in C. If you'd like to understand it better you can send me an e-mail to rodolk@yahoo.com or we can open another thread to discuss it.